# WebSocket connection for updates tries to switch to insecure

Tags: bug, web-sockets

There is currently a bug in Stack Overflow JS that leads to realtime updates failure.

I load SO pages through HTTPS; e.g. Active questions for a tag, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension?sort=active

This normally works, as well as realtime updating: first connection to the realtime updates endpoint is made through `wss:` regardless of the page's protocol:

> wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/

However, as the page stays up, the code decides to switch to `ws:`, again, regardless of the page's protocol:

> ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/

This reset seems to happen after 5 minutes of inactivity in the tag and leads to 2 distinct problems.

1. When loading the page over HTTPS, Chrome simply refuses to allow the connection and realtime updates break:

   > [blocked] The page at 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension?sort=active&pageSize=50' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

   The script does not recover from this and updates stop.
2. My workplace is behind a transparent squid proxy. This breaks insecure WebSockets, so accessing the page over HTTP just leads to connection errors when `ws:` endpoint is accessed:

   > WebSocket connection to 'ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

   However, the script <del>*does* recover</del> sometimes recovers from that and reconnects through `wss:` automatically.

Please note: I'm reasonably sure this worked before (about a month before). In any case, the connection should not downgrade to `ws:`.

Comment: This question probably should be migrated to stackoverflow for more attention and since it is mostly a technical question, and not primarily about stackoverflow.

Comment: @wallyk What? I would argue it can be migrated to Meta.SE, but definitely not SO (since it's a question/bug report about SO/SE, it's a Meta question)

Comment: +1 this is so irritating... wish it would get fixed

Comment: Seen today on SO:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/5771128/charlie-joynt' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

Comment: Still happening today as well