# Why is my connection to Meta/SO so scadgy/unpredictable?

Tags: support

[Perhaps related to this bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278720/921224)

### What I experience

On all stack overflow sites, but especially meta I experience connection issues. My issues are usually:

1. I try to load a page but it never loads or times out.
2. I try to post a comment/answer/question but it never posts.
3. An up-vote that I cast keeps disappearing.
4. I click on my inbox or achievements buttons, the dropdown appears but never populates. Interestingly there is never an issue with this when I am on my own profile page!
5. Just noticed now that after a couple of times, the suggested `similar questions` section has entered a permenant loading state.

Whilst having problems with a particular site, I still seem to be able to use other sites unhindered.

### What I've tried

By *never* I mean I've actually left my PC loading a page for 5-10 minutes before refreshing, when the page then loads instantaneously.

I can relieve these issues by `ctrl + f5`ing the page repeatedly untill it loads (usually almost instantly once it finally works)

### My setup

I'm located in central (non-rural) UK if that might make a difference, I get the issues mostly at work though I also get them at home.

The internet speed is capable of streaming video and audio without repeated buffering so speed doesn't seem to be the issue.

I use the official chrome browser, up to date but not beta.

At home I have fiber to property, at work something slower.

---

I have to remove any part of the URL beyond the `?`, e.g. `?noredirect=1#comment355927_325907`to post a comment at all.

---

Whilst writing this question something changed which stopped anything new loading (similar questions, inbox, auto-complete on tags) **however** the number of notifications in my inbox kept updating.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox 45 Win7, maybe its your connection thats scadgy?

Comment: @Magisch completely possible, however the fact that it occurs from two locations, miles apart with different internet providers over different infrastructure leads me to believe that maybe something else is at play

Comment: Different locations. But - different ISP? Different DNS servers?

Comment: Different ISP yes, different DNS... don't know, how can I check? (took over 10 attempts to post this reply... tried to respond immediately... got logged out...)

Comment: What does the browser's network debugging tab say?

Comment: If using windows `ipconfig /all` will list the DNS servers (amongst other things)

Comment: @RobertLongson Upon load, some items at random seem to get stuck in the `pending` status before becoming `101` (switching protocols) for even longer.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm just following links, I never manually type URLs

Comment: I don't use any URL mangling plugins.

Comment: @Oded DNS servers look like no ip address I've ever seen, is it secure to post them publicly?

Comment: @Troyseph - sure. Guessing though that they are [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addresses, not IPv4 ones. If you *only* use IPv6, that could be the problem here.

Comment: @Oded `fec0:0:0:ffff`, I'm not able to change any settings at work at all (seriously locked down machines) but at home I'm definitely not limiting my access to be via ipv6.

Comment: Yeah, that's IPv6, @Troyseph. No IPv4 there at all? Could be old DNS records that are caches locally - try purging them (`ipconfig /flushdns`)

Comment: @Oded tried, should this question perhaps be migrated to another site? It is becoming less meta and more technical >< **addendum** does the fact that this comment didn't immediately send after the flush mean it didn't work?

Comment: Retagged as [tag:support], as it really is a support question. It is fine here as such (though we _could_ hop into chat). When you open your browser dev tools (F12) on the network tab and hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) - what is taking lots of time? Any network errors?

Comment: In regards to your update (link to possible bug report) - *are* you using https everywhere? We don't officially support that yet.

Comment: Maybe change your DNS server settings, and try with Google's DNS or OpenDNS  ? Sometimes ISP provided DNS servers are flakey. If it's an option, you could also use a VPN or Tor.

Comment: @Oded how do I know if I'm using https everywhere? The address is just `meta.stackove....` without the usual http or www prefix.

Comment: Depends on the browser - most of them will have a green lock icon on the address bar for https. It isn't there otherwise.

Comment: @Oded No green lock, definitely not https, chome definately does when it is https.

Comment: In that case, perhaps try _with_ https ? Maybe something is interfering with your traffic - you can type `https://stackoverflow.com` in the adress bar, and it will use HTTPS - does it work if you do that ?

Comment: Can you go to http://teststackoverflow.com and see what is slow there? (if you past the guid here, I can look things up on our end)

Comment: @Oded the two bottlenecks seem to consistently be Request start and DOM loading, each taking about the same time, which is 10 times longer than any other field. I have refreshed the page many times and this behaviour seems consistent. My issue appears to be with submitting data and auto-reloading page items, as opposed to initial page load times. Apart from the times when the pages don't ever load, though I've yet to get that to happen when loading the test page...

Comment: I just got `Request URL:wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols` in my browsers Network debugger.

Comment: Telling me those are 10x longer than other fields doesn't actually tell me anything - that's why I asked for the GUIDs so I can look for myself and see what the numbers are like (could be normal and that 10x could be expected). Also the `wss:` thing is a red herring that's web sockets.

Comment: Are you connecting over wifi? What is your latency like? (ping both stackoverflow and your router - perhaps there are packtes getting dropped there? Or the network timing out?).

Comment: @Oded sorry I missed the bit about the `"guid": "e4239151-b8fc-42f0-88ff-5f30d0e79fbb"`. I'm not connected over wifi at either location, my ping time to stackoverflow is `8ms` average, `0%` packet loss, left it pinging while having page loading and comment posting issues.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cookies and logging back in?

Comment: @Oded Just tried it, testing... This comment worked instantly, very exciting! And the edit worked straight away.

Comment: So, looks like something duff with your cookies was the problem :)

Comment: @Oded lets hope so, it could just be a coincidence, comments do work sometimes... migrating this to chat is being a pain =/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114596/discussion-between-troyseph-and-oded).