# When unable to upload an image to a question, the error code is somewhat unhelpful

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Unfortunately I am unable to replicate the error to take a screenshot but when attempting to upload an image to a question it failed and the error code was.

> [error] I'm a teapot

After reloading the webpage the problem seemed to have resolved itself.
([Note that I've already asked a question regarding my unpredictable and stop-start connection to stackoverflow, perhaps it is related.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325907/why-is-my-connection-to-meta-so-so-scadgy-unpredictable))

Comment: [MSE: Stack Overflow returning HTTP error code 418 (I'm a teapot)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot)

Comment: "After reloading the webpage the problem seemed to have resolved itself." - closing as nor reproducible.

Comment: @Oded I wasn't reporting the fact that I couldn't upload a picture, I was reporting the unhelpful error code, perhaps I shouldn't have tagged as a bug, and instead tagged as discussion?